# Jar depedency in aar archive

Tags: apache, tomcat, apache-axis

I'm building a new Axis2 REST Service who's using some JAXB classes inside.

The JAXB classes are embedded inside a Jar file (let's call it JAXB.jar)

The architecture of my aar file is like this :

**service.aar**

- org \ company \ **myService.class**
- META-INF \ **services.xml**
- lib \ **JAXB.jar**

Inside my **myService.class** file I call JAXB classes with the package they have inside the Jar file...

But when I start my server (Tomcat), I get an error like :

> Error: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: null...

I also tried to move the **JAXB.jar** file inside my **axis2** webapp lib folder, but same message.

Any idea of what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: FYI, the method in my service is returning a JAXB object. Maybe its the problem ?

Comment: Actually it was the problem. Sorry for the inconvenience I'll update and close when I'll be able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to return a JAXB Object in my Service Method. My bad.